# Is it possible to put a unicode character in a jira description

Tags: utf-8, jira

I want o put a downward chevron in my jira ticket description. THe opposite of ^  I have the unicode number but I'm not sure of a way of adding this to the description. Is this possible?

(To give some background Im trying to draw a one to many db line)

Thanks

Comment: Which version of JIRA? I know that 5.5 fails with some unicode characters in comments.

Comment: Fails for me tight now too. Considering I'm testing a lot of Unicode stuff at the moment it's a huge annoyance.

Answer (score 3):

Even in Jira 6.4.x I couldn't find an out-of-the-box-solution. But provided that you or your Jira administrator enabled the "html" module of the "Wiki Renderers Macro Plugin" (and the Wiki Style Renderer is used for the description field) you could use the following workaround with the HTML entity of the Unicode character:

```
{html}&#x2304;{html}
```

Due to XSS security implications the html module is disabled by default and shouldn't be enabled without careful consideration - at least for public Jira instances.

Comment: It seems you can skip the `{html}`-tags. Just writing `&#x0141;` works for me at least, but I don't know how much tweaking my jira-administrators have done...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the backing database is. For MySQL, it probably won't work yet. For PostgreSQL, it should work fine.

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-36135

Answer (score 0):

You could use you OS emoji's
With the key combination `Control+Command+Space` on the Mac or the `Windows+Period` in Windows